# Issues in polling a file using Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, polling

My req. is to poll a directory for a specified time interval say 10 mins. If a file of a particular extension say *.xml is found in the directory then the it just consumes (i.e. picks and deletes) the file and prints the name else after the specified time (say 10 mins.) interval it sends out a mail that the file has not been picked (i.e. consumed) or the file has not come.

There are 2 options either I do it through Spring integration OR WatchService of Core Java. Following is the code in Spring Integration which I have written till now:

```
<int:channel id="fileChannel" />
<int:channel id="processedFileChannel" />

<context:property-placeholder location="localProps.properties" />

    <int:poller default="true" fixed-rate="10000" id="poller"></int:poller>

    <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter
        directory="file:${inbound.folder}" channel="fileChannel"
        filename-pattern="*.xml" />

    <int:service-activator input-channel="fileChannel"
        ref="fileHandlerService" method="processFile" output-channel="processedFileChannel"/>

    <bean id="fileHandlerService" class="com.practice.cmrs.springintegration.Poll" />
```

The above code is successfully polling the folder for a particular file pattern. Now I have 2 things to do:

1) Stop polling after a particular time interval (configurable) say 10 mins.

2) Check whether a file with a particular extension is there in the folder ... if the file is there (it consumes and then deletes) else it sends an email to a group of people (email part is done.)

Please help me in the above 2 points.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Smart Poller](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#__smart_polling) to do things like that.

You can adjust the poller and/or take different actions if/when the poll results in a message.

> Version 4.2 introduced the AbstractMessageSourceAdvice. Any Advice objects in the advice-chain that subclass this class, are applied to just the receive operation. Such classes implement the following methods:

```
beforeReceive(MessageSource<?> source)
```

> This method is called before the MessageSource.receive() method. It enables you to examine and or reconfigure the source at this time. Returning false cancels this poll (similar to the PollSkipAdvice mentioned above).

```
Message<?> afterReceive(Message<?> result, MessageSource<?> source)
```

> This method is called after the receive() method; again, you can reconfigure the source, or take any action perhaps depending on the result (which can be null if there was no message created by the source). You can even return a different message!

Comment: could I please have a simple example for the same? .... I am not getting any example from the net as well ... so its getting difficult .... an example would be helpful.

Comment: Not with a single one, but you could use two cron triggers in a `CompoundTriggerAdvice` [javadocs here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#_compoundtriggeradvice).